# How to use geminabox with Apache web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, rubygems

I want to use `geminabox` with `Apache` web server. I have searched a lot on web but could not find any concrete information. Can some one please let me know how to do this ? Will appreciate detailed suggestions.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to use Geminabox with Apache is to configure a HTTP Reverse Proxy.

For this configuration, you just need two files:

**1)** The `config.ru` just like the example in the README.md file in the [geminabox repository](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox):

```
require "rubygems"
require "geminabox"

Geminabox.data = "include here the data path"
run Geminabox::Server
```

To run the server use `rackup` command. This will start the server in the 9292 port. If you want to change the port number use `rackup -p XXXX`.

**2)** In the Apache side, make sure that you have the `mod_proxy` and the `mod_proxy_http` installed. If yes, just include the following lines into your Apache config file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9292/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9292/
```

Restart the Apache and it is done!

Answer (score 0):

`geminabox` is a ruby application, and just like all ruby applications, Apache does not support them out of the box.

With that said, a simple Google of how to use ruby applications with Apache lead me to [this](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy), which lead me to [this](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). I have no experience with this tool. However, it is suggested by the rails team, so it has to have some merit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am learning rails and slowing catching up with things. I am looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

I did work with Apache VirtualHost.

In folder `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` create a file `gems.conf`, so add it to the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gems.mydomain
        ServerAlias gems.local
        DocumentRoot /var/railsapps/gems/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `/var/railsapps/gems` is the folder that have the `config.ru`.

The domain `gems.mydomain` must be in your DNS or `/etc/hosts`